# Expose a specific port to be accessible by my outgoing ip address on kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes

I am trying to run a p2p client (IOTA) which requires the node I am connecting to to be able to connect back to be on the same ip address I made the request from and to a very specific port.

NodePort won't work because it exposes as a different port then what I want.
LoadBalancer won't work because the other node won't know my load balancer ip address.

How are people able to use p2p clients like bitcoin or iota on kubernetes?

Comment: I'm getting confused on what you asked. Are you trying to establish a p2p between two nodes or node and a external machine? If its the latter, you can definitely map ports using the loadbalancer. May be Im confused.

Comment: p2p between two nodes (mine within the cluster and someone elses outside the cluster). The node I am connecting to is expecting to be able to connect back on the same ip the request was made from - and on a specific port. If I use a load balancer, my request ip and expected incoming ip will be different.

Answer (score 0):

Because each pod has a dynamic IP address and, usually, a dynamic name (for example, if you use `Deployment`), you don't have a chance to make its' endpoint static somehow, but you have an alternative way - [StatefulSet](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/statefulset/) with [Headless Service](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#headless-services).

You can deploy several replicas of your application using `StatefulSet` and create `Headless Service` for it. Each replica in the `StatefulSet` will be available using its unique name.

Here's the quote from the documentation:

> Each `Pod` in a `StatefulSet` derives its hostname from the name of the `StatefulSet` and the ordinal of the Pod. The pattern for the constructed hostname is `$(statefulset name)-$(ordinal)`. The example above will create three Pods named `web-0`,`web-1`,`web-2`. A `StatefulSet` can use a `Headless Service` to control the domain of its `Pods`. The domain managed by this `Service` takes the form: `$(service name).$(namespace).svc.cluster.local`, where “cluster.local” is the cluster domain. As each `Pod` is created, it gets a matching DNS subdomain, taking the form: `$(podname).$(governing service domain)`, where the governing service is defined by the `serviceName` field on the `StatefulSet`.